# Sanity check ±12 V/+5 V PSU PCB

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, kicad

I'm building a small Eurorack switching PSU using DC-DC converter modules, and before pulling the trigger on the PCB I'd love to have someone sanity check the board.

The schematic is pretty straightforward; I pretty much followed the datasheets for both the RDDW60F-12 and SKM10B-05, adding a handful of LEDs to monitor power on each rail, and inputs/outputs for power and an external (daisy chainable) switch to enable/disable the DC-DC converters.

[image: Schematic]

This is what the PCB looks like: bottom layer is a ground plane, and the top layer has a ground fill everywhere where aren't traces, connected to the bottom ground plane using via stitching.

I'm not entirely sure if it's useful (saw this being used on the [Befaco PCBs](https://shop.befaco.org/power-solutions/945-excalibus-diy-kit.html)), but I cut out some slots under the converters to help with cooling.

What am I missing? Doing anything wrong? Feedback greatly appreciated!

[image: PCB]

Comment: Welcome! Seems resonable. Are there any requirements on input and output capacitors for the DC/DC modules? Any particular reason for THT resistors and LEDs?

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to get by with two layers, four layers is probably not needed with the cross sectional area of copper with the current levels (~3 amps) that you have.

Other than that you might want to run some resistance/heating calculations on those traces outputs from the DC to DC converters. I don't know how much current they're carrying but if they're carrying more than 3 amps you could probably expand their size a little bit or a lot. Usually on power traces I run power planes or fills if I can instead of traces, it usually doesn't cost anything and if you have the space, use it.